# Using the blend instructions in intel intrinsics (AVX)

Tags: c++, c, intrinsics, avx, immediate-operand

I have a question regarding the AVX `_mm256_blend_pd` function.

I want to optimize my code where I use heavily the `_mm256_blendv_pd` function. This unfortunately has a pretty high latency and low throughput. This function takes as input three `__m256d` variables where the last one represents the mask that is used to select from the first 2 variables.

I found another function (`_mm256_blend_pd`) which takes a bit mask instead of a `__m256d` variable as mask. When the mask is static I could simply pass something like  `0b0111` to take the first element from the first variable and the last 3 elements of the second variable. However in my case the mask is computed using `_mm_cmp_pd` function which returns a `__m256d` variable. I found out that I can use `_mm256_movemask_pd` to return an int from the mask, however when passing this into the function `_mm256_blend_pd` I get an error `error: the last argument must be a 4-bit immediate`.

Is there a way to pass this integer using its first 4 bits?  Or is there another function similar to movemask that would allow me to use `_mm256_blend_pd`? Or is there another approach I can use to avoid having a cmp, movemask and blend that would be more efficient for this use case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_mm256_blend_pd` is the intrinsic for [`vblendpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blendpd) which takes its control operand as an immediate constant, embedded into the machine code of the instruction.  (That's what "immediate" means in assembly / machine code terminology.)

**In C++ terms, the control arg must be `constexpr`** so the compiler can embed it into the instruction at compile time.  You can't use it for runtime-variable blends.

It's unfortunate that variable-blend instructions like `vblendvpd` are slower, but they're "only" 2 uops on Skylake, with 1 or 2 cycle latency (depending on which input you're measuring the critical path through).  ([uops.info](https://www.uops.info/table.html?search=blendvp&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_SKX=on&cb_ICL=on&cb_ZEN%2B=on&cb_ZEN2=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_base=on&cb_avx=on&cb_avx2=on)). And on Skylake those uops can run on any of the 3 vector ALU ports.  (Worse on Haswell/Broadwell, though, limited to port 5 only, competing for it with shuffles).  Zen can even run them as a single uop.

There's nothing better for the general case until AVX512 makes masking a first-class operation you can do as part of other instructions, and gives us single-uop blend instructions like `vblendmpd ymm0{k1}, ymm1, ymm2` (blend according to a mask register).

In some special cases you can usefully `_mm256_and_pd` to conditionally zero instead of blending, e.g. to zero an input before an `add` instead of blending after.

---

**TL:DR: `_mm256_blend_pd` lets you use a faster instruction for the special case where the control *is* a compile-time constant.**

Comment: Can you use `_mm256_permutevar_ps` instead of `blend`?

Comment: Oh I see, now it makes more sense. I bit unfortunate but thanks a lot for the clarification. I have to stick with blendv then.

Comment: @anatolyg: `vpermilps` does take a vector control operand, but it's a shuffle with only 1 data input.  I'm not seeing any obvious way to blend with it.  If you have something in mind, maybe ask the OP in a comment under the question.